# Converting a non-static list to a static list

Tags: java, list, static

I was asked this question in interview and can't find a solution to it:

> I have declared a list in my class. During its declaration, I haven't
>   made it static. But after adding some data to it, I want to make it
>   static. Is it possible?

We are allowed to change the data type of the list.

**Edit**: Is it not possible to declare an array of static type and then convert the list to array and hence make it static?

Comment: Does it mean changing list to static at runtime?

Comment: What is meant by "static" here? The modifier? Or static vs. dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: @trutheality: static means 'the modifier' here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not using standard java, but you actually *can* manipulate the running byte code using a library such as [Javassist](http://www.jboss.org/javassist); technically the answer is "yes", but you may be shot by the team leader if you actually do this.

Answer (score 3):

No. Declaration are at compile time. Adding some data is at run time. You can't change the declaration at run time - therefore the answer is no.

...but why would you want to do anything like that?

Comment: As I asked, I was asked this question in an interview. I wasn't informed as to why the person wants to do it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the declaration at runTime.

When you write code, you need to compile your code (including your declaration) into byte-code or native binary.

Otherwise, for those function call static function but there isn't any static declaration, you will get error at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your interviewer had in mind, but you can't change this specific list variable to become static at runtime.

But now I will speculate. Since primary reason to make it static is to have single copy of the list per class and be able to access it via class rather than instance, what you could do at run time is to assign this list to some static variable and then it will be accessible in such way. Of course, if you have multiple instances of class with different copies of list, it becomes logically impossible without some kind of merge. Again, I can just speculate on what you interviewer wanted.